# DAO like functionality on Gnosis?

Tags: dao, voting, gnosis-safe, function

I am a Gnosis newbie. Want to set up a safe for an investor group. It seems like the safe has awesome functionality for that. As the group potentially expands beyond my small circle,  may offer participation by other people. Besides integration into existing DAO solutions like Aragon, Colony, etc, are there any ways within Gnosis to have “token holders owners” join, but not have transaction approval authority?  Basically, have a safe function as a DAO of sorts on its own?  Just want to streamline as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The Zodiac team from Gnosis is building DAO tools around the Safe. There are quite some extensions already and the community is open for new proposals.

You can find more information on the [Zodiac GitHub repo](https://github.com/gnosis/zodiac) and [their medium page](https://gnosisguild.mirror.xyz/OuhG5s2X5uSVBx1EK4tKPhnUc91Wh9YM0fwSnC8UNcg).

Gnosis itself is using the Zodiac tools to manage their DAO funds. This is done by a combination of [Snapshot](https://snapshot.org/#/gnosis.eth), [Realitio](https://realityeth.github.io/#!/token/GNO) and [the Safe](https://gnosis-safe.io/app/eth:0x0da0c3e52c977ed3cbc641ff02dd271c3ed55afe/balances).